# Scala adding the result of a function call to the value in a map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I came across a weird functionality of Scala where the following two are not equivalent:

```
var map = Map[A,B]() 
map += ( key -> (valueGen(key)))
```

does not give the same result as

```
var map = Map[A,B]() 
val result = valueGen(key)
map += ( key -> result)
```

The second snippet does what you expect it to while the first one does not add correctly to the map, it instead overwrites the previous value so that the map only contains the most recently written value to it instead of all the values added into it.

Comment: Well, what are the different results you are getting? It looks like they should return the same thing

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this before, and it only causes problems when the `valueGen` function and this code is recursive together.  I believe this is because expressions in parentheses are not guaranteed to be executed first. Parentheses only bind operators. Scala must be interpreting the += on the map like this:

`map = map + (expression)`

When it executes `map + (expression)`, it reads the map operand to the plus operator first and holds it. Then it attempts to evaluate `(expression)`. In the case `(expression)` contains the call to the `valueGen` function, it makes the call and then adds it to the *cached* map from this particular call. If the call to `valueGen` ends up recursing around and calling this function (and modifying the map first), this will overwrite those changes with the cached version from this call + the result. That is why you want to call the `valueGen` function separately from the += operator if your function is recursive.

Answer (score 1):

When I run

```
object test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        var map = Map[String,Int]()
        map += ("hello" -> (valueGen("hello")))
        map += ("bye" -> (valueGen("bye")))
        println(map)
    }

    def valueGen(x: String) = x.length
}
```

I get

```
Map(hello -> 5, bye -> 3)
```

Could you provide a runnable example of what you are seeing?